# Unable to show the context menu in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

can anyone please help me out for the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
>
> at line editor.contextMenu.show(editor.document.getBody(), null, x,
>   y); in plugin.js

Comment: More details, please. What is your code? What are you trying to do when you receive this error?

Comment: I was going through below link: https://github.com/navalgandhi1989/ckeditor-autocomplete-suggestions-plugin   I basically want to implement autosuggestio in ckeditor.

Comment: This is a third-party plugin. Open an issue in its repository. Additionally update your question here because nobody is able to guess from the text that you're having this issue when trying to use this particular plugin. Thanks!